# Language mode "docker compose" with unknown error "Unexpected scalar at node end(UNEXPECTED_TOKEN)"

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code, docker-compose, syntax

I create a docker compose file which is correct 100%, but vscode see some error, this is very annoying

May be somebody can explain?

[image: docker compose]

Comment: That looks like a PNG file, not a Compose YAML file?  The file of which you've included a screenshot isn't valid YAML (`{{ openldap_volume_data }}:/var/lib/ldap` isn't a valid YAML-scalar volume specification).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reason of VSCode alert is obviously invalid `YAML` syntax of your file. According to specific syntax and directory name I can conclude it's template of compose file.

But, thanks to flexible `YAML` specification, you can try to make it valid.

Try to enclose in quotation marks your volumes items (like  `- "{{ ldap_...}}:/dir/"`), seem it will satisfy vscode, docker compose and your template engine.